# debo hacer routing dinamico a mi url

Tags: fetch, backend, nextjs

estoy construyendo routing dinamico con next.js 12 y debo hacer fetch con la url que se ve en la imagen adjunta a esta pregunta, dicha url es de mi propio backend e intento hacer el routing con el elemento **numSerie**, he intentado a poner al final de la url "?, [numSerie], &" y otras cosas y no logro que funcione. que me sugieren y muchas gracias por su colaboración.

Comment: Antes que te den negativos y/o te cierren la pregunta. Lectura altamente sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.